# Why does molten wax stick to surfaces when it soldifies?

Tags: liquid-state, adhesion

In a candle, when wax is molten and cools after. It sticks to the glass surrounding it, why does this happen?

Comment: Don't know a lot about it myself, but if you want to search, the phenomenon is called _[wetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting)_.

Answer (score 0):

The molecules that make up glass are populated with oxygen and hydrogen atoms and those of the wax are populated with hydrogen atoms. Weak *hydrogen bonding* is therefore possible between the hydrogens in glass and those in the wax when they meet; in essence, the wax looks a little like glass to the glass molecules and the glass looks a little like wax to the wax molecules, and you get a mild attractive force between them. That bonding is relatively weak, so it is possible to break it by prying the wax loose with a butter knife.

Comment: When you say hydrogen bonding, did you mean "between the hydrogens in glass and oxygen/nitrogens in the wax" rather than "those in the wax"?

Comment: I mean between glass and wax.